# How to use SQL select results in another sub select in same query / statement?

Tags: sql, plsql

This is a little hard to explain - hopefully it is an easy solve.  I have a table that I am doing a select on.

Here is the general query:

```
SELECT id, sub_id, name, inception_date, pc_code FROM investments;
```

This will pull everything which is great - but I need to use the sub_id field data that is returned from this select statement to re-query the table and pull in the name of the sub id.  Here is what I am after in psudo code:

```
SELECT id, name, **sub_id**,
(SELECT name FROM investments where id = (sub_id from outer select statement)),
inception_date, pc_code
FROM investments;
```

`sub_id` and sub_id names would just query the same table for id and name.

I hope this makes sense and thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't need a subselect but double use of the same table with outer join, try this and be aware that the two columns from the table using sub_id can be null in case there is no match.

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.id , b.name, a.inception_date, a.pc_code
FROM investments a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN investments b ON b.id = a.sub_id;
```

Comment: Thanks - big help!

Answer (score 0):

Is this work?

```
WITH cte as (SELECT id,  name FROM investments )
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.sub_id,  a.inception_date, a.pc_code , b.name
FROM investments a
INNER JOIN cte b on b.id  = a.sub_id ;
```

Or easier

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.sub_id,  a.inception_date, a.pc_code , b.name
FROM investments a
INNER JOIN investments b on b.id  = a.sub_id ;
```

Comment: Thanks - big help!